Как сделать slash комманды в discord.py
Я только начинаю делать дс ботов, мне нужна реализация slash комманд, к сожалениию, в интернете ничего стоящего не нашёл, можете подсказать пожалуйста, как это сделать, ну или хотя бы направить меня в нужном направлении.

https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands

тут name - имя команды, description - описание:
import config

import discord
from discord import app_commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)


@tree.command(
    name = 'test',
    description="My first application Command")
async def first_command(interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(interaction.user.id)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await tree.sync()
    print("Ready!")

client.run(config.dsTOKEN)


пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
